# Increase EXT4 size on Debian whilst preserving Data in a VM?

Tags: filesystems, diskmanagement, fdisk

I've been trying to increase the partition size on one of our servers as it was created years ago and was set too small. I've increased the size in the VM that hosts this but now I'm trying to get Linux to know we've allowed more space.

The details from fdisk /dev/sda are below

```
root@server:~# fdisk /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.25.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 40 GiB, 42947575808 bytes, 83881984 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x488006fc

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         128 19529855 19529728  9.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       19529856 83878271 64348416 30.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       19529984 22239487  2709504  1.3G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       22239616 83878271 61638656 29.4G 83 Linux


Command (m for help):
```

So I want to increase sda6 to 70GB, what is the best way to go about this? I can't use parted as the package isn't installed and the server currently has no internet access. I've tried doing it via fdisk by deleting the partition and  recreating it larger, but when I try and mount it I get errors regarding superblocks.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Similar question/answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67095/how-can-i-expand-ext4-partition-size-on-debian

Comment: What hypervisor is it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton VMWare 5,5

Comment: @Bert I've followed that exact guide with no luck. When I try and remount it I have the superblocks issues

Comment: Your error is probably due to the start/end blocks.  Make sure you use the exact same 'start' number, as given in the print.

Comment: It's also worth noting, that you probably need to either force a disk scan, or do a reboot of the machine, before it notices the physical disk size has changed.